# Create and check if point is inside polygon

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have a `std::list` of 2D points and would like to test if one point `p` lies inside the polygon given by the vector. I already found that `boost::geometry` has a function `within` to test this. Unfortunately I seem to use it in the wrong way:

```
void someFunction(...) {
    namespace bpl = boost::polygon;
    typedef bpl::polygon_data<double> Polygon;
    typedef bpl::polygon_traits<Polygon>::point_type Point;

    Polygon polygon;
    std::vector<Point> points;

    for (std::list<MyPointType>::const_iterator it = myPolygonPoints.begin(); it != myPolygonPoints.end(); ++it) {
        points.push_back(Point(it->GetX(),it->GetY()));
    } 

    polygon.set(points.begin(),points.end());
    // ...
    if (!boost::geometry::within(Point(someX,someY),polygon)) {
        doSomething();
    }
    //...
}
```

I get various compile errors, starting by unmatched types in the call of `within`.
So what is the correct way to build a polygon and use it with `within`?

Greetings

Comment: and the errors are... ?

Comment: 1st of all, the `for` is out of scope, then you call `.set` out of scope. Who's `m_PolygonPoints`? Who's `temp`?

Comment: Since the code includes some transformations and calculations, I did not post everything. I edited the code, maybe now it is a little more clear. The error given is: `boost-1_50\boost/geometry/core/point_type.hpp(47): error C2664: 'boost::mpl::assertion_failed': Converting of parameter 1 of 'boost::mpl::failed ************(__thiscall boost::geometry::traits::point_type<Geometry>::NOT_IMPLEMENTED_FOR_THIS_POINT_TYPE::* ***********)(boost::mpl::assert_::types<T1>)' in 'boost::mpl::assert<false>::type' not possible`

Comment: Note that you mix Boost.Geometry and Boost.Polygon, which are two different boost libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not stick with the types that are given in the examples? See [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html), for instance.

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> Point;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point> Polygon;
```

For me it works then.

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
//...

Polygon poly;
//... construct the polygon

Point p(4, 1);

std::cout << "within: " << (boost::geometry::within(p, poly) ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
```

Comment: How do I add points to the polygon in this case? There is no set function or anything like this.

Comment: like this: poly.outer().push_back(Point(0,0));

Comment: maybe you should read about the polygon concept, for the exact meaning of outer() and inners(): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts/concept_polygon.html

Comment: The preferred way to add points is using append: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/append.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an example from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html

Based on what you mean, the code:

```
if (!boost::geometry::within(Point(someX,someY),polygon)) {
        doSomething();
}
```

should be:

```
Point point(someX,someY);
if (!boost::geometry::within(point,polygon)) {
        doSomething();
}
```

or:

```
   Point *ppoint = new point(someX,someY);
   if (!boost::geometry::within(*ppoint,polygon)) {
            doSomething();
   }
```

Because direct call for constructor Point(someX,someY) as a function without class instantiation is not allowed in C++.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. See the error message in the comment above.

Comment: @user1228633 see within function declaration: template<typename Geometry1, typename Geometry2>
bool within(Geometry1 const & geometry1, Geometry2 const & geometry2) —— is bpl::polygon_traits<Polygon>::point_type a derived class of template class Geometry1?

Comment: Since it is not working, I doubt it is. And this is kind of the question - how do I have to create the polygon / point to work with `within`? There are so many different ways and types in boost, that I have no idea, which one is a 'correct' `Geometry`